# Collapse specific rows of a dataframe using dplyr syntax but maintain the other row details

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame where I wish to summarize specific rows of a data frame and I would ideally like to do this in a single dplyr pipe chain.

My data frame looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"), subgroup = c("BOO","BOO","BOO","BOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","MOO","MOO","MOO","MOO","ZOO","ZOO","ZOO","ZOO","KOO","KOO","KOO","KOO"),x = c(8,12,26,4,13,14,21,16,1,30,24,10,20,9,7,23,19,28,29,25),y = c(24,22,23,26,11,1,19,10,21,13,27,20,7,9,17,5,18,6,30,25))
```

For subgroup == MOO I wish to summarise columns x and y using sum and I would like to keep the last group value i.e. C (note row 9).

[image: These are the rows to be collapsed to a single value]

[image]

From this data frame I can filter out the rows of interest, summarise them and then bind_rows again but I'd like to understand if its possible to do this in a single dplyr pipe

Here's what my expected data frame looks like:

```
result <- data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"), subgroup = c("BOO","BOO","BOO","BOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","MOO","ZOO","ZOO","ZOO","ZOO","KOO","KOO","KOO","KOO"),x = c(8,12,26,4,13,14,21,16,65,20,9,7,23,19,28,29,25),y = c(24,22,23,26,11,1,19,10,81,7,9,17,5,18,6,30,25))
```

Notice how these "MOO" rows get collapse to a single row where the group value is modified to the last value, in this case "C"

Comment: are the values in the expected correct.  I would request to use `set.seed` as `sample` is used in the input

Comment: @akrun yes the expected values are correct. Note how the B and C gets collapsed to the last value i.e. C

Comment: I guess I understand your logic, but I cannot crosscheck with your expected output as the input varies because of seed not used

Comment: @akrun, sorry I just updated the OP

Comment: Sorry, it was just the values I got confused.  Please check the output now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
 df %>%
 mutate(across(c(x, y), ~ replace(.x, subgroup == "MOO", 
   sum(.x[subgroup == "MOO"])))) %>%
   filter((subgroup == "MOO" & 
   !duplicated(subgroup, fromLast = TRUE))| subgroup != "MOO")
```

-output

```
  group subgroup  x  y
1      A      BOO  8 24
2      A      BOO 12 22
3      A      BOO 26 23
4      A      BOO  4 26
5      A      FOO 13 11
6      B      FOO 14  1
7      B      FOO 21 19
8      B      FOO 16 10
9      C      MOO 65 81
10     C      ZOO 20  7
11     C      ZOO  9  9
12     C      ZOO  7 17
13     D      ZOO 23  5
14     D      KOO 19 18
15     D      KOO 28  6
16     D      KOO 29 30
17     D      KOO 25 25
```

Comment: thanks so much this is a really neat way to do this. Thanks again